# Ubuntu server partitions not updated after repartioning

Tags: ubuntu, gparted

I'm running last version of ubuntu server on VirtualBox. I ran of of disk space so I changed the vdi size using Vmanage. Attached the disk used by this VM to another VM and repartioned the disk using gparted. Started the first VM again (ubuntu server) and df -h still shows the previous partitioning.

What am I doing wrong here? I have been going nuts over this for hours now. Can't figure out why in gparted it shows the correct size and partitions and in ubuntu it's the old size. I'm absolutely positive it's the same disk.

Thank you for your time...

Screenshots attached : [Screenshot 2 (gparted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1eji.png) | [Screenshot 3 (df -h)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miCW8.png)

Comment: You mentioned attaching the disk to a different VM in order to repartition it using GParted.  Did you remember to re-attach the disk to the current VM?  Also you could boot your current VM using [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and resize the disk directly in the current VM.  NOTE that VirtualBox requires booting in **KMS Mode** for the latest GParted Live versions to work -- see [GParted News](http://gparted.org/news.php).

Answer (score 0):

You did it right, just forgot to extend it to the new allocated space

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```